# Action bar with tabs on the top and additional buttons below

Tags: android, tabs, navigation, android-actionbar

I'm trying to figure out navigation in the app I'm making, and want it to look like it does on the phone to the right (link below), except I want the menu at the bottom to be directly below the tabs. I tried googling and searching for hours, but I cant seem to figure out.

I have managed to make the tabs (with Fragments and such).

I apologize if this really isn't that hard, but being new to this it is kind of hard to wrap your head around everything. Either way, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a custom layout. 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html
Look at section 5, should be pretty simple from there.

That being said, don't fight the OS. I always ask myself questions like: Do you really need tabs above a menu? Can you quote another application doing that?

Comment: Yes, that was what I were looking for. Thank you very much! As for the motivation: We wanted something that looked a bit like the Facebook-app (With the menu on top with notifications, msgs, etc, and a menu beneath with options for writing statuses and so on). Although, a while after asking the question I realized this solution wouldn't actually make sense. So you are right, and I will take your method of thinking with me! Thanks.